# Is Data-Structure and Algorithm same for all programming languages?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

If a person learns **data-structure and algorithm** in one programming language does it needs to learn other language's **data-structure and algorithm** ?
As i am about to start a book **Data-structure and algorithm in JavaScript** as i also want to learn Web
will it help me for other languages too?

Comment: This question is a bit too broad, however, a good answer is that the implementation details will vary between languages but the core structures and algorithms themselves will be the same.

Comment: I can think of one difference: some programming languages, usually called "functional programming languages" (Haskell is one example), forbid updates (writes) to existing variables.  That means they have only a subset of the data structures available to other ("imperative") languages.  That said, those data structures can be simulated, with varying efficiency, and then the same set of algorithms can be implemented with them.

Comment: It will help in other languages but not in all languages (I can think VHDL, Labview, Fortran as exception, but sure there are others)

Comment: Trying to build a suffix tree in Prolog might be.... interesting...

Comment: Related: [Programmers: Do I need to understand algorithms and data structures to be called a programmer?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/18406/do-i-need-to-understand-algorithms-and-data-structures-to-be-called-a-programmer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Data structures and algorithms are concepts that are independent of language. Therefore once you master them in you favorite language it's relatively  easy to switch to another one.

Now if you're asking about built-in methods and apis that different languages have, they do differ, but you shouldn't learn specific APIs in your data-structure and algorithms book anyways.

Answer (score 4):

Yes... and no.

While the concepts behind algorithms and data structures, like space and time complexity or mutability, are language agnostic, some languages might not let you implement some of those patterns at all.

A good example would be a recursive algorithm. In some languages like haskell, recursivity is the best way to iterate over a collection of element. In other languages like C, you should avoid using recursive algorithm on unbound collections as you can easily hit the dept limit of the stack. You could also easily imagine a language that is not even stack based and in which a recursive algorithm would be completely impossible to implement. You could implement a stack on top of such a language but it would most definitely be slower than implementing the algorithm in a different fashion.

An other example would be object oriented data structures. Some languages like haskell do not let you change values. All elements in such language are immutable and must be copied to be changed. This is analog to how numbers are handled in javascript where you cannot change the value 2, but you can take the value 2, add 1 to it and then store it to a new location. Other languages like C do not have (or very poorly handle) object oriented programming. This will break down most data structure pattern you will learn about in a javascript oriented book.

In the end, it all boils down to performance. You don't write C code like you write JavaScript or F# code. They all have their quirks and thus need different implementations even though the idea behind those algorithms and structures will stay the same. You can always emulate a pattern on a language that does not supports it, like OOP in C, but it will always feel more natural to solve the problem in a different way.

That being said, as long as you stay within the same kind of language, you can probably reuse 80%+ of that book. There are many OOP languages out there. Javascript is probably the most exotic of them all with its ability to treat all objects like dictionaries and its weird concept of "this" so a lot of patterns in there will not apply in those other languages.

Answer (score 2):

The data structure and algorithm as concepts are the same across languages, the implementation  however varies greatly.

Just look at the implementation of quicksort in an imperative language like C and in a functional language like Haskell. This particular algorithm is a poster boy for functional languages as it can be implemented in just about two lines (and people are particularly fond of stressing *that's it*).

There is a finer point. Depending on the language, many data structures and algorithms needn't be implemented explicitly at all, other than as an academic exercise to learn about them. For example, in Python you don't really need to implement an associative container whereas in C++ you need to.

If it helps, think of using DS and algo in different programming languages as narrating a story in multiple human languages. The plot elements remain the same but the ease of expression, or the lack thereof, varies greatly depending on the language used to narrate it.

Answer (score 2):

You need not learn data structure and algorithm when you use another language.The reason is evident, all of data structures and algorithm is a realization of some kinds of "mathmatical or logical thought".

for example,if you learn the sort algorithm, you must hear about the quick sort and merge sort and any others, the realization of different sort algotithm is based on fundamental element that almost every language has,such as varible,arrays,loop and so on. i mean you can realize it without using the language(such as JavaScript) characteristics.

although it is nothing relevant to language,i still suggest you stduy it with C.The reason is that C is a lower high-level language which means it is near the operating system.And the algorithm you write with C is faster than Java or Python.(Most cases).And C don't have so many characteristic like c++ stl or java collection. In C++ or Java, it realize hashmap itself.If you are a green hand to data structure, you'd better realize it from 0 to 1 yourself rather directly use other "tools" to lazy.

Answer (score 1):

(DSA) Data structures and algorithms are like emotions in humans (in all humans emotions are same like happy, sad etc)

and, programming languages are like different languages that humans speak (like spanish, english, german, arabic etc)

all humans have same emotions (DSA) but when they express them in different languages (programming languages) , the way of expressing (implementation) of these emotions (DSA) are different.

so when you switch to using different or new language, just have a look at how those DSA are implemented in that languages.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question, and I've asked myself the same thing before.

The reality is that Data Structures are sets of abstracted mathematical logics at the level of computing, nothing more. Choosing the right data structure to solve specific problems is essential and a highly sought-after skill.

Therefore, regardless of the programming language, the essence of all this is the same. From my experience, I can guarantee that it is better for you to learn data structures with a language you are more accustomed to, and this will be better for your learning.

It's no use wanting to learn data structures 100% using Assembly. Will you learn? Probably yes. But it will be 10,000 times more difficult than using Javascript, for example. Just be careful not to use ready-made functions without knowing what's under the hood, like sort, map, reduce, and others.

Always try to understand the core of the language, how things are organized behind the scenes, and you'll do well!